# delete confirmation in ruby-on-rails using jQuery UI dialog to make normal http request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I am showing delete confirmation box using jQuery UI dialog. But on delete I don't want to make any ajax call when user click on delete, as after deleting I want to redirect to home page. The delete should make normal http request with method delete. How can I achieve it?

```
$("#delDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                if (gohome) // redirect to home
                    {
                        //here I want to make normal call to delete post without using .post/.get/.ajax
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would say, you can make a .ajax() call with method as delete and then use window.location.replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure ryan from railcasts.com shows you how to exactly what your after in one or two of his screencasts.

Have a squiz, because I ws looking at using html delete requests without an ajax call and saw his way on his screencasts.

Comment: I did try to find the solution on that site, could not found it. It would be a great help to me if you could provide me the link.

Comment: @Bongs  try this link.http://railscasts.com/episodes/77-destroy-without-javascript?autoplay=true     sorry thought I had posted it in